# TCL code to replace () with blank line

Tags: tcl

Hi i am newbie in TCL please help me with code, method anything. There is a string for example 
   (abcgfhdskls12345)HELLO(hikjkflklfk)
         (bkjopkjjkl)HI(kjkkjjuilpp)

i just want to remove everything between () and want to print only Hi and Hello

Answer (score 3):

You could use Tcl [`regsub`](http://www2.tcl.tk/987) to remove anything with parentheses around it:

```
set x "(abcgfhdskls12345)HELLO(hikjkflklfk) (bkjopkjjkl)HI(kjkkjjuilpp)"
regsub -all {\(.*?\)} $x  {} x
puts $x
```

which yields:

```
$ tclsh foo.tcl
HELLO HI
```

Comment: You should probably use `[^()]*` instead of `.*?` here; that has more predictable behavior when malformatted input is about. (Well, more predictable for non-mavens of RE engines.)

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to use the `regsub` command, which performs substitutions based on regular expressions. You can write something like this:

```
set str {(abcgfhdskls12345)HELLO(hikjkflklfk) (bkjopkjjkl)HI(kjkkjjuilpp)}
set result [ regsub -all {\(.*?\)} $str {} ]
```

The `-all` option is required because your pattern may appear more than once in the source string and you don't want to strip just the first.

The text inside `{...}` is the pattern. You want to match anything that is inside brackets, so you use the `\(...\)` part; escaping brackets is required because they have a special meaning in the regular expressions syntax.

Inside brackets you want to match any character repeated zero or more times, so you have `.*?`, where the *dot* means any character and the `*?` is the zero-or-more non-greedy repeating command.

Answer (score 0):

You could also split the string on open or close parentheses, and throw out the odd-numbered elements:

```
set s "(abcgfhdskls12345)HELLO(hikjkflklfk) (bkjopkjjkl)HI(kjkkjjuilpp)"
foreach {out in} [split $s "()"] {puts $out}
```

```
HELLO

HI
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a way using regexp only.

```
set p {(abcgfhdskls12345)HELLO(hikjkflklfk) (bkjopkjjkl)HI(kjkkjjuilpp)}
set pol [regexp {(.*)(HELLO)(.*) (.*)(HI)(.*)} $p p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6]
puts "$p3 $p6"
```

o/p: HELLO HI